# How to display an image for few seconds on load?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to display an opening screen image that will last 5 seconds once the app loads. I'm using setTimeout but it won't work. Does anyone have an idea?

````
import OpeningScreen from '../../../../../../assets/images/OPENING_SCREEN.png';

function ProgressComponent() {
  const [isOpeningScreenVisible, setOpeningScreenVisible] = useState(true)
   setTimeout(() => {
     setOpeningScreenVisible(false);
   }, 5000);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
      }}
    >
      {isOpeningScreenVisible && <img src={OpeningScreen} className="image" />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProgressComponent;```
````

Comment: Check my answer it should work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the img src.

From

```
 {isOpeningScreenVisible && <img src={OpeningScreen} className="image" />}
```

To this

```
 {isOpeningScreenVisible && <img src={OpeningScreen.src} className="image" />}
```

Comment: It gives me error

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it works fine. try these:

- check your image path and be sure it's correct.
- check and see if there is any error in the console and fix all of them.
- maybe the loading time is taking more time than 5000ms. try 10000ms for showing the image.

Comment: I tried with 10000ms and it didnt work. The image shows and disappears immediately.

Comment: So the image is loaded. now inspect the elements of your app and see what's hiding your image before 10000ms. there might be an element that covers your image. also, check the console for the isOpeningScreenVisible state and see when it changes the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code to use native events so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

What i would do:

```
import OpeningScreen from '../../../../../../assets/images/OPENING_SCREEN.png';

function ProgressComponent() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
      }}
    >
        <img
            src={OpeningScreen}
            alt="opening screen"
            onLoad={e => {
                console.log("init event")
                setTimeout(() => (e.target as HTMLImageElement).remove(), 5000)
            }}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProgressComponent;
```

Anyway, this isn't the best approach. The best you can do is to use css transitions to animate just an opening screen

Comment: I tried your code as well but src={OpeningScreen.src} is giving me an error when I hover on "src": Property 'src' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: It depends on which framework you're using, on nextjs it's correct to use `.src`, in plain react you can use directly the imported value. At this point i guess you're using plain react so i'm updating my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Is it relevant if i'm using Electron?

Comment: Have you tried to use just css?

Comment: No, because it's an actual image. I just want it to appear 5 seconds once the app is loaded.

Comment: I understood but with css (or [animejs](https://animejs.com/) if you want) you can wait for the image to load and then use a transition to hide it after 5 secs and trust me, that would so much more performant since you're not using javascript or heavy operations. Animejs use css transitions under the hood so it's the same

Comment: Ok, I will google it and see what I can find :) Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250369/discussion-between-ilan-edri-and-nick).

Answer (score -1):

```html
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
      setLoading(true);
    } else if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 5000);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "black" }}>
      {loading && (
        <div id="loadingScreen">
         <img src={OpeningScreen} className="image" />
        </div>
      )}
      {!loading && (
        <div className="App" id="app"></div>
    </div>
```

#### Try this It should work as it is still working in one of my project

> The Basic Idea is the `<img src={openingScreen}/>` will be on the screen untill the react build file is loaded to on the site.
> Add the everything inside  `<div className="App" id="app"></div>` once they are loaded the image will fade.

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary heavy code, img supports events just like every other tag